# Поиск ключей в файле 6ГБ на python

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть файл с ключами. Структура файла такова:

```
ключ 1/n
ключ 2/n
ключ 3/n
...
ключ m
```

Я могу его прочитать в DataFrame. И мне надо потом проверять наличие ключей в этом фрейме.

Например, есть ли `ключ q` в это фрейме. Пробовал несколько вариантов и самый бытсрый из них:

```
Key in df[0].values
```

Но это всё равно медленно. Как можно ускорить это дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из самых быстрых способов будет создать `set` ключей и проверять в нем.

[Python утверждает, что проверка наличия ключа в множестве - это, в большинстве случаев, операция со сложностью `O(1)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set).

```
# подготовка 
chk_set = set(df[0])
# проверка
if key in chk_set:
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно работает!